# Why would unpacking be preffered over passing in a list

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, iterable-unpacking

Unpacking argument lists:

```
def send(*data):
    for datum in data:
        ser.write(datum)
```

vs sending in a list in the first place:

```
def send(data):
    for datum in data:
        ser.write(datum)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it simplifies the API for the case where otherwise you'll *always* have to pass in a list:

```
send(something, otherthing)
```

versus:

```
send([something, otherthing])
```

where your *usual* parameters are taken from different locations; e.g. `something` and `otherthing` are more likely to be separate variables than already collected in one list.

The Python 3.x `print()` function does exactly that, as well as the `os.path.join()` function. You rarely have all your print arguments or path-elements-to-join combined in a list before calling the API.

Compare:

```
os.path.join(rootdirectory, relativepath, filename)
print('Debug information:', localvariable)
```

vs.

```
os.path.join([rootdirectory, relativepath, filename])
print(['Debug information:', localvariable])
```

If `.join()` or `print()` were to accept only one positional argument (a list), the users of the API would find themselves typing the `[` and `]` brackets over and over again.

By accepting a variable number of positional arguments, you save users of your API the trouble of having to create  list just for the function call. In the rare cases where the parameters have already been collected into a list, they can use the `*params` calling convention:

```
send(*params)
```

to echo your function signature.

Comment: If you pass `[something]` to the function with the splat operator, the list gets treated as a single element, where are the function without splat would iterate over that list. Are you saying there are two different use cases? or you should always use the first way?

Comment: It simplifies the call regardless of the number of elements, as long as they aren't already in a list for other reasons. `send(x, '+', y, '=', y + y)` beats `send([x, '+', y, '=', y + y])`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: reworded and expanded; original version was really barking up the wrong tree. Blame it on Christmas spirit distractions at my home office, if you will. :-)